# Unable to connect to server Pg Admin 4

Tags: postgresql

При подключении к серверу в Pg Admin 4 получаю вот такую ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

host name/adress=localhost
port=5432

Comment: а подключиться через консольный клиент получается?

Comment: простите, я новичок в этом, что такое "консольный клиент"?